# Should I mail the recruiter if no response from interviewer after positive technical interview

Tags: hiring-process, job-offer, follow-up

I wrote a written test in a software firm. As far as I know, I scored top. Then they called me for interview for the engineering position. The interview went well. Then they called me again for another interview about 1 week later. I attended the interview. There were only 3 candidates left. Then after 2 days, they called me to meet the CTO (Chief Territory Officer) in an interview. As far as I know, I was the only person to get call to meet CTO. The CTO said that I would get call for a last interview with HR. Then 20 days passed, no call / mail came.  This is 26 jan, if they hire me then I need to leave my current job. Also, I might get another job but everything is hanging because of that.  Is it OK to contact HR myself to confirm my last interview?

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: I've submitted an edit to make your question avoid "what should I do?" and rather ask a specific, answerable question.  Hopefully it still fits what you are trying to ask and can be accepted.

Comment: I would personally check in every 7 days unless specifically instructed not to do so. It lets them know you're interested and keeps you in their mind. It sounds like you initially got a lot of interest from them and then heard nothing, I wouldn't have let 20 days go past. Ultimately they are looking to hire someone so if they get upset because you're emailing every week then move on.

Answer (score 4):

You should have followed up and asked for a confirmation of your interview last week - You don't let twenty days go by. Two weeks, maybe. Not three weeks. In fact, since the CTO said that you would get a last interview with HR and it took a week to get the interview with the CTO, you should have used one week as a yard stick to follow up - You are two weeks overdue for a follow up interview.

Call/email HR immediately and tell them what you just told us: that the CTO told you that the last interview is with HR. And that you take his words as a prime indicator that you passed the technical interview. And either arrange that last interview with HR or get that notice of rejection.